# Need to configure my header in the middle page of a longtable so I can change the caption

Tags: header-footer, captions, longtable

E.g., if the table has to break at some point, the new header changes the name of the topic to topic (cont.), not in the beginning or the end.

PS: I can't create two or more longtables since I will be listing every table...

```
\documentclass[
12pt,               
openright,          
twoside,            
a4paper,            
hyphens,
paginasA3,  
english,
brazil
]{ifsp-spo-inf-ctds}\usepackage{verbatim}\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{style}

\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{abntex2cite}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}

\usepackage{pdfpages}           
\begin{longtable}[!htb]{|
                p{0.125\textwidth -2\tabcolsep - 10.25\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{0.175\textwidth -2\tabcolsep - 10.25\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{0.275\textwidth -2\tabcolsep - 10.25\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{0.175\textwidth -2\tabcolsep - 10.25\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{0.25\textwidth -2\tabcolsep - 10.25\arrayrulewidth}|}
    \caption{}\label{}
    {\rhead{cont.}}
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
                \textbf{Cod} &
                \textbf{Name} &
                \textbf{Description} &
                \textbf{Priority} &
                \textbf{Relation}
                \\\hline
    \endhead
    \caption*{Source: the authors}
    \endfoot
    \hline
        RF01 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF02 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RF01 \\\hline
        RF03 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF04 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RF01 \\\hline     
        RF05 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF06 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RF01 \\\hline
        RF07 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF08 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RF01 \\\hline
        RF09 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RNF01\\\hline
        RF10 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RF01 \\\hline
        RF11 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF12 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RF01 \\\hline
        RF13 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF14 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RF01 \\\hline 
        RF15 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF16 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RF01 \\\hline  
        RF17 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RNF01\\\hline
        RF18 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RF01 \\\hline      
        RF19 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RNF01\\\hline
        RF20 & \lipsum & \lipsum & High & RF01 \\\hline
        RF21 & \lipsum & \lipsum & Low & RNF01\\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please extend your code fragment to complete but small document with your table beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: and please make clear, what you like to obtain. change page header at each part of table? or like to have caption on the top of each part of table with `(cont.)` at all part except the first?

Comment: Sorry, my english is awful. I want to have caption on the top of each part of table with (cont.) except the first and the last ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your mwe (minimal working example) is not complete. in preamble is missed the main package: `longtable` and than `\begin{document}`
- i havent your packages and documentclass, however principle how to manage `longtable` can be shown with document class `article`
- i change columns specifications that one table row be placed on one page
- for calculation of columns width you need `dimexpr` macro, see mwe below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[!htb]{|
        p{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth -2\tabcolsep-0.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
        p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth -2\tabcolsep-0.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
        p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth -2\tabcolsep-0.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
        p{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
        p{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
\caption{my very long table}
\label{} \\
    \hline
\textbf{Cod}
    & \textbf{Name}
        & \textbf{Description}
            & \textbf{Priority}
                &   \textbf{Relation}   \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{my very long table (cont.) }  \\
    \hline
\textbf{Cod}
    & \textbf{Name}
        & \textbf{Description}
            & \textbf{Priority}
                &   \textbf{Relation}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Source: the authors}}
\endlastfoot
    \hline
RF01 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF02 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RF01 \\\hline
RF03 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF04 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RF01 \\\hline
RF05 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF06 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low  & RF01 \\\hline
RF07 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF08 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RF01 \\\hline
RF09 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low & RNF01\\\hline
RF10 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RF01 \\\hline
RF11 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF12 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low & RF01 \\\hline
RF13 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF14 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RF01 \\\hline
RF15 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF16 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low & RF01 \\\hline
RF17 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low & RNF01\\\hline
RF18 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low & RF01 \\\hline
RF19 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RNF01\\\hline
RF20 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & High & RF01 \\\hline
RF21 & \lipsum*[11] & \lipsum*[11] & Low & RNF01\\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]